# I am getting issue while making post request to durable functions (extension of Azure Functions) from ADF and from Postman

Tags: azure-functions, http-status-code-404, azure-data-factory, azure-durable-functions

I am able to call azure functions from ADF and postman but when I call durable functions from ADF or postman it gives me error:

```
Operation on target Azure Function1 failed: Call to provided Azure function '' failed with status-'NotFound' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - NotFound.'.
```

I have tried everything but dont know why this is happening. I have created durable function through portal in functionApp as follow:

**DurableFunctionsHttpStart1:**

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    // Function input comes from the request content.
    dynamic eventData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // Pass the function name as part of the route 
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1", null);

    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}
```

**DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1:**

```
/*
 * This function is not intended to be invoked directly. Instead it will be
 * triggered by an HTTP starter function.
 * 
 * Before running this sample, please:
 * - create a Durable activity function (default name is "Hello")
 * - create a Durable HTTP starter function
 */

#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"

public static async Task<List<string>> Run(DurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var outputs = new List<string>();

    // Replace "Hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Hello1", "Tokyo"));
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Hello1", "Seattle"));
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Hello1", "London"));

    // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
    return outputs;
}
```

**Hello1:**

```
/*
 * This function is not intended to be invoked directly. Instead it will be
 * triggered by an orchestrator function.
 * 
 * Before running this sample, please:
 * - create a Durable orchestration function
 * - create a Durable HTTP starter function
 */

#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"

using System;
using System.Threading;

public static string Run(string name)
{
    Thread.Sleep(260000);
    return $"Hello {name}!";
}
```

**From ADF side I am calling DurableFunctionsHttpStart1 function, which will call orchestrator function and activity will be called. Please guide**

Comment: Also face this problem when use postman to call the httpstart?

Comment: @BowmanZhu. An update, So in postman I was using wrong url so that why i was getting 404 - function NotFound. URL seems to be https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1 but I was trying with https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/api/DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1. So I was missing orchestrator in it. But how i will call it in ADF? I have created a linked service with function app and function key but getting 404 - NotFound. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Reproduce your error on ADF, this is what you are facing now:

[image]

If your function in ADF is like this, you will get the above error.
[image]
(Also the method need to be post)

This is the configuration of the azure function in ADF should be:

[image]

Then it works fine on my ADF.

**Original Answer:**

These code work fine on my side:

**DurableFunctionsHttpStart1**

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    string functionName,
    ILogger log)
{
    // Function input comes from the request content.
    dynamic eventData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // Pass the function name as part of the route 
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1", eventData);

    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}
```

**DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1**

```
/*
 * This function is not intended to be invoked directly. Instead it will be
 * triggered by an HTTP starter function.
 * 
 * Before running this sample, please:
 * - create a Durable activity function (default name is "Hello")
 * - create a Durable HTTP starter function
 */

#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"

public static async Task<List<string>> Run(DurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var outputs = new List<string>();

    // Replace "Hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Hello1", "Tokyo"));
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Hello1", "Seattle"));
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Hello1", "London"));

    // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
    return outputs;
}
```

**Hello1**

```
/*
 * This function is not intended to be invoked directly. Instead it will be
 * triggered by an orchestrator function.
 * 
 * Before running this sample, please:
 * - create a Durable orchestration function
 * - create a Durable HTTP starter function
 */

#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"
using System;
using System.Threading;
public static string Run(string name)
{
    Thread.Sleep(260000);
    return $"Hello {name}!";
}
```

And all the function triggered well, at last:

[image]

Comment: An update, So in postman I was using wrong url so that why i was getting 404 - function NotFound. URL seems to be https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1 but I was trying with https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/api/DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1. So I was missing orchestrator in it. But how i will call it in ADF? I have created a linked service with function app and function key but getting 404 - NotFound. Please guide.

Comment: @BilalShafqat I have update my answer. Check if your function name is wrong. And the method should be POST.

Comment: @BilalShafqat Any questions? I'm going to bed,if you have more doubts please leave me a message.

Comment: yes I have... I was missing Orchestrator in function name in ADF.

Comment: But even after mentioning, I am still unable. let me try again and I will reach you in a minute.

Comment: Thanks alot @BowmanZhu. I am able to run it through ADF. I was doing 2 mistakes. 1) In the function Name in ADF I was not mentioning "orchestrators". And 2) Instead of function Name "DurableFunctionsHttpStart1" i mentioned function Name "DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1". So here is another thing I want to ask: I think I should be calling "DurableFunctionsHttpStart1" function as it is a HTTP function and then this function should call Orchestrator function but calling HTTP function "DurableFunctionsHttpStart1" gives me function NotFound. Please guide.

Comment: @BilalShafqat Hi, Bilal. Thanks for your sharing. The function name in ADF should be the part of the url of your DurableFunctionsHttpStart1. The url is getting from [this place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bgvO.png). On my side, the url is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVx43.png). The function name should be part of the url. On my side, it is orchestrators/{functionName}